# The variance of forecasted time serie data

Tags: r, forecasting, variance

I have used forecast() to the first 1526 data points in my data serie VIX,  estimating the final 300 data points. I want to measure the goodness of fit with the variance of the difference between actual historical data and forecasted result. Is there an easy way of doing this in R?

The code currently is

```
r_vix_3b=diff(log(VIX[,"Close"]))
num_train=1526 
h=300
plot_start=1300 
plot_labels=126      # interval between x-axis major tick marks
data_fcst_pts=num_train:(num_train+h) 

fit_1step=auto.arima(r_vix_3b[1:num_train])
forecast_1step = forecast(fit_1step, h=h)
plot(forecast_1step, xaxt="n", xlim=c(plot_start, num_train+h), ylim=c(-0.3, 0.3))  #ylim=range(r_vix)
points(data_fcst_pts, r_vix_3b[data_fcst_pts],col="blue", type="l", pch=16)
axis(1, at=seq(0,length(r_vix_3b)+h-1,plot_labels), labels=VIX$Date[seq(2, length(r_vix_3b)+h,plot_labels)] )

diff_1_step = r_vix_3b[1526:1825] - forecast_1step
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check `?accuracy` function from **forecast** package.

I guess in your case it would be something like:

```
acc <- accuracy(forecast_1step,diff_1_step)
```